# remove json object specfic values

Tags: spring, boot

JSON representation
fruit: {
"type": "sweet",
"value": "Apple"
}
I want to perform concise representations   like this.

**fruit: "Apple"**

Comment: Are you using the jackon or gson library?

Comment: jackson  library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the string to JsonNode and then iterate over nodes and replace its value also check not a null child to avoid replacing a single node with a null value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
    String data =
            "{ \"id\": \"123\", \"type\": \"fruit\", \"veritey1\": { \"type\": \"Property\", \"value\": \"moresweetappler\" }, \"quantity\": { \"type\": \"Property\", \"value\":10 } }";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode nodes = mapper.readTree(data);
    Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> iterator = nodes.fields();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, JsonNode> node = iterator.next();
        if (node.getValue().hasNonNull("value")) {
            ((ObjectNode) nodes).set(node.getKey(), node.getValue().get("value"));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(nodes.toString());
}
```

Output:
`{"id":"123","type":"fruit","veritey1":"moresweetappler","quantity":10}`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
    String data =
            "{ \"tank\": { \"type\": \"Relationship\", \"object\": \"id007\", \"time\": \"2017-07-29T12:00:04Z\", \"providedBy\": { \"type\": \"Relationship\", \"object\": \"id009\" } } }";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode nodes = mapper.readTree(data);
    Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> iterator = nodes.fields();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, JsonNode> node = iterator.next();
        reduceJson(node.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println(nodes.toString());
}

public static void reduceJson(JsonNode node) {
    if (node.hasNonNull("type")) {
        ((ObjectNode) node).remove("type");
    }
    Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> iterator = node.fields();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, JsonNode> childnode = iterator.next();
        if (childnode.getValue().isObject()) {
            reduceJson(node.get(childnode.getKey()));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
`{"tank":{"object":"id007","time":"2017-07-29T12:00:04Z","providedBy":{"object":"id009"}}}`

Comment: thank you for your response. but suppose we have an entity like this 
{
    "id": "123",
    "type": "fruit",
    "veritey1": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": "moresweetappler"
    },
    "quantity": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value":10 
    }
} 
then above snippet do all remaining value is null
so please provide a Null value  only for "type":"Property"

Comment: Please provide the expected output of `{ "id": "123", "type": "fruit", "veritey1": { "type": "Property", "value": "moresweetappler" }, "quantity": { "type": "Property", "value":10 } }`

Comment: expected output is this **{ "id": "123", 
"type": "fruit", 
"veritey1": moresweetappler" ,
 "quantity": 10
 }**

Comment: Updated answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response, 
in another case I have another JSON instance on this instance I want to perform optimization on this arttr.. 
**"tank": {
  "type": "Relationship",
  "object": "id007",
  "time": "2017-07-29T12:00:04Z",
  "providedBy": {
   "type": "Relationship",
   "object": "id009"
     }
 }**  
I want this JSON representation to  like this **"tank": {
  "object": "id007",
  "time": "2017-07-29T12:00:04Z",
  "providedBy": {
  "object": "id009"
  }
 }** please guide me on how to do this on the same entity "id":123

Comment: @vivekkumar Updated code for same. You need to use recursion to parse the tree and remove data in it.

Comment: thanks ,
** if (node.hasNonNull("providedBy")) {
         reduceJson(node.get("providedBy"));
     }**
in the if   condition can we get the   (**String data** )  providedBy dynamically instead of provided hardcoded, please guide me because sometimes we change porvidedBy into 
providedByOne then this logic will be fail so please guide me on how to do this. Thanks 
for your support

Comment: up to that it is working fine , can we get the **providedBy value dynamically instead of hardcoded value like **if (node.hasNonNull("providedBy")) { reduceJson(node.get("providedBy")); }** please gudie me

Comment: Added dynamic way to find children and update as well.

Comment: thank you again for your valuable response, some other hand in putting 
in same **ID** with attr like **"Temp": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": 25,
        "uc": "tc",
        "time": "2022-03-14T01:59:26.535Z"
    }**
and getting a response like **"Temp":  25**
but in my case, I want to like this 
**"Temp": {
        "value": 25,
        "uc": "tc",
        "time": "2022-03-14T01:59:26.535Z"
    }**
please guide me on how to do this, 
your last post Is helping me lots.
Thanks again

Comment: You can use a second program for the same. Please understand the code and develop the logic of what you want to achieve. Will not be able to solve every different input you get.

Comment: thanks for your support , 
can we do same thing without using **ObjectMapper class** 
instead of **ObjectMapper** class can we use other logic for do same thing please 
guide me how to do this without **ObjectMapper**

Comment: The comments are too long now and it would be better to have a new question. So others can also answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

```
const data = '{  "fruit": {    "type": "sweet",    "value": "Apple"  }}';
const obj = JSON.parse(data);

for (let key in obj) {
    console.log(key, obj[key].value); // "fruit",  "Apple" 
}
```

Comment: Thanks , can you guide me 
geting the response in postman like this
frut: {
        "type": "sweet",
        "value": "Apple"
    }
and same thinks I how I can do with spring boot  application

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.